# Pyqt5 QTableItem всегда возвращает None

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Я пытаюсь создать таблицу для матрицы инцидентности, чтобы затем выгружать из неё данные и строить граф, однако, когда я пытаюсь понять, есть ли в ячейке единица, то почему-то для первого значения возвращается 1, а для остальных None.

```
def color_graph(self):
      model = self.tblMatrix.model()
      graph = []
      print(model.columnCount(), model.rowCount())
      for i in range(1, model.columnCount()):
         graph.append([])
         for j in range(1, model.rowCount()):
            index = model.index(i, j)
            print(i, j, model.data(index))
            graph[i-1].append(str(model.data(index)))
```

Непонятно, почему он так себя ведёт. Код выше выполняется при нажатии на кнопку.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На картинке пример вывода массива `graph` и сама форма с таблицей. У меня также есть подозрение, что это может быть связано с частотой обновления таблицы, но не понятно почему. Как исправить данную ситуацию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас перепутаны индексы строк (row) и столбцов (column), правильно так:

```
      print(model.rowCount(), model.columnCount())
      for i in range(1, model.rowCount()):
         graph.append([])
         for j in range(1, model.columnCount()):
      ...
```

Пример:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem

app = QApplication([])

table = QTableWidget()
table.setColumnCount(2)
table.setRowCount(4)

table.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem(''))
table.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem('v1'))
table.setItem(2, 0, QTableWidgetItem('v2'))
table.setItem(3, 0, QTableWidgetItem('v3'))

table.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem('e1'))
table.setItem(1, 1, QTableWidgetItem('1'))
table.setItem(2, 1, QTableWidgetItem('2'))
table.setItem(3, 1, QTableWidgetItem('3'))

model = table.model()

print(model.rowCount(), model.columnCount())
for i in range(1, model.rowCount()):
    for j in range(1, model.columnCount()):
        index = model.index(i, j)
        print(f'{i}x{j}: {model.data(index)}')

table.show()

app.exec()
```

Вывод:

```
4 2
1x1: 1
2x1: 2
3x1: 3
```